# junit method assertLinkPresentWithText

Tags: junit, htmlunit, case-sensitive

This method checks for a link which has the String that is passed as argument. I have a doubt whether it is case sensitive match or not.

Exmaple :
I have a link in anchor tag with "sample123" as the text inside the anchor tag.
if I use this method as assertLinkPresentWithText("Sample");

Will this match the link that as the text sample in lowercases?

Comment: No, link matching is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](http://htmlunit.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/htmlunit/trunk/htmlunit/src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebAssert.java?revision=7303&content-type=text%2Fplain):

```
/**
 * Verifies that the specified page contains a link with the specified text. The specified text
 * may be a substring of the entire text contained by the link.
 *
 * @param page the page to check
 * @param text the text which a link in the specified page is expected to contain
 */
public static void assertLinkPresentWithText(final HtmlPage page, final String text) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (final HtmlAnchor a : page.getAnchors()) {
        if (a.asText().contains(text)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        final String msg = "The page does not contain a link with text '" + text + "'.";
        throw new AssertionError(msg);
    }
}
```

I would say **no**.